# Data grouping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this:

```
Age    Sex
23     Male
34     Female
38     Female
32     Male
33     Female
20     Male
34     Male
```

I need to group it and tabulate it so that it looks like this

```
  Age       Male  Female
21 - 25      2      0
26 - 30      0      0
31 - 35      2      2
36 - 40      0      1
```

How can I do this is Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so as follows.

Start by setting a `'count'` column to 1:

```
df['count'] = 1
```

Now make another column of the age group. In the array in the next line, place whatever boundaries you like:

```
df['age_group'] = pd.cut(df.Age, [20, 31, 36])
```

Now, all you need to do is pivot the table using the age group as the index, gender as the columns, the count as values, and the aggregation as sum:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('count', index='age_group', columns='Sex', aggfunc='sum')
Sex Female  Male
age_group       
(20, 31]    NaN 1
(31, 36]    2   2
```

If you want, you can further change the `NaN`s with `fillna`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table('count', index='age_group', columns='Sex', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
    Sex Female  Male
age_group       
(20, 31]    0   1
(31, 36]    2   2
```

Comment: Thanks, why did you create column 'count' and set to 1 but didnt use it further?